# Using Android/Firebase Invite System

Tags: android, firebase, google-app-invites

I have implemented AppInviteInvitation today with Android and can succesfully send an invite but when the recipient tries to press the install button within the invite they are taken to plus.google.com in their device browser.

Am I doing something wrong?

```
  private void onInviteClicked() {
    Intent intent = new AppInviteInvitation.IntentBuilder("Invite")
            .setMessage("Download")
            .setCallToActionText("Install")
            .build();
   final int REQUEST_INVITE = 0;
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_INVITE);
 }
```

Comment: I have the same problem, and the Google Plus link returns a 404 error. Only an SMS invite opened on my Android phone takes me to the Play Store. All email links fail with 404 on G+. Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the deep link property to your app name.

```
.setDeepLink(Uri.parse(getString(R.string.app_name)))
```

I was getting a 404 error on the Google Plus link until I added the above statement to the Intent builder. After adding the statement, the invites behaved as expected. I am not using deep links in my application, though they are enabled for the app via the Google Play console.

Comment: It does help! Thanks a lot!

Comment: can i create this invite link using rest api ?